# How to detect if currency in not supported Paypal API?

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a project that uses Paypal Payment Processor. The project sets the payment currency in our end. Now the problem is the currency in our end is not supported in Paypal's User Account. My Question is: How would our end know that the set payment currency in our end is not supported in the Paypal's User Account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an actual API check you could run for this. Optionally you can accept all currencies and have PayPal convert it via current conversion rates.

Take a look @ https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/

Comment: Here is what I did, I made a function "tryPay Function" basically mocking the paypals pay api that returns an error if the currency is not supported in the Paypal's User Account. And give our end an error if the currency is not supported through "CURRENCY_NOT_SUPPORTED" flag. Anyways, I will look into your suggestion. Thank you @Brian!